# Docker containers performance difference between OSX and Linux

Tags: python, linux, performance, docker, containers

I recently switched from OSX (el capitan) to Ubuntu (16.04) and I'm working on a Python project which makes use of docker containers for integration tests with different databases (I have containers for mysql, postgres and so on).
What shocked me is that I noticed that my test suite runs about 4 times slower than when I was using OSX! (And it takes ~4 minutes instead of ~1, not 12 seconds instead of 10... so it's actually a big issue!).
I suppose that the problem is on docker containers, since the tests that take the most time are the ones related to databases, the other ones run in few milliseconds (often close to the 0), so I don't think it's a problem related to Python or something else.

The only difference between my current setup and the previous is that on Linux I'm not using docker-machine because is not necessary (it's instead mandatory in OSX or Windows to run containers).

I'm also using docker-compose to launch my containers, so I have the same configuration (database and OS versions) I was using before...

So, I realize that my question is too broad but... what's going on here? How can I find the bottleneck?

Ps: docker version is 1.11.1 and compose 1.5.2

**UPDATE:**

it seems that I'm not the only one facing this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/677248/docker-performance-on-ubuntu-host-2x-worse-than-osx-host

Comment: Docker on OSX runs in a virtual machine (VirtualBox), whereas on Linux (for which it was originally developed) it runs directly against the kernel. There are projects on the way (for example, mentioned [here](http://blog.hypriot.com/post/first-touch-down-with-docker-for-mac/)) that should provide better Docker performance on Mac, but AFAIK they aren't yet available for the general public.

Comment: yep, so why on Linux it runs 4 times slower?! :/

Comment: Oh duh sorry, I misread, I thought OSX was slower :P You're running on the same hardware I assume?

Comment: yes, same hardware (macbook pro i7 with 8GB of ram)... it's a nonsense... it should run 4 times faster rather than slower XD

Comment: My guess would be slow I/O performance in Ubuntu (OS X is obviously optimized for that hardware), might be worthwhile to check.

Comment: An apples to apples comparison would be to compare linux host vs containers on the same linux host with database volumes mounted with -v.